# Reconnect automatically reverse ssh connection

Tags: ssh

I'm running:

```
ssh -N -R 2222:localhost:22 phil@myserver.com
```

Which is working but I want to keep this connection open so I can always access my pi. When I tried after waiting a day or two I couldn't connect. When I checked the tmux session on my pi it said:

> Write failed: Broken pipe

How can I setup a script up to re-connect automatically?

Comment: `autossh` should bring answer to your problems.

Answer (score 5):

For people looking for this now, I found a systemd service to be much more reliable than autossh (running Debian 10.4). In my case autossh regularly failed after some days, the systemd solution is running for weeks/months without issues.

Content of /etc/systemd/system/ssh_remote_access.service :

```
[Unit]
Description=SSH reverse tunnel
After=network.target

[Service]
User=PUT_YOUR_LINUX_USER_NAME_HERE
Restart=always
RestartSec=20
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ssh -o "ServerAliveInterval 30" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 3" -o "ExitOnForwardFailure yes" -N -R 2222:localhost:22 phil@myserver.com

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And then activate the service:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable ssh_remote_access
sudo systemctl start ssh_remote_access
```